# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestErrorMessageResult' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have created a webapi get method to return images with a blob storage URL.

But I need to handle exceptions as well, how should I do it in this case? I get an error in the last line of the catch

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetProfileImage(string url)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

            try
            {
                //Initalize configuration settings
                var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:name"];
                var accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:key"];
                var profilepicturecontainername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:profilepicscontainername"];

                //Instance objects needed to store the files
                var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(profilepicturecontainername);

                //Gets blob reference
                var cloudBlob = await blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(new Uri(url));

                //Check if it exists
                var cloudBlobExists = await cloudBlob.ExistsAsync();

                //Opens memory stream
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    cloudBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
                    response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync(b.Length).Wait();
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }          
        }
```

Comment: `return new HttpResponseMessage { new StringContent("Error Lulo: " + guid), StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I get this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

Comment: I corrected my comment... `return new HttpResponseMessage { new StringContent("Error Lulo: " + guid), StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };`

Comment: Invalid initializer member declarator

Comment: `return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("Error Lulo: " + guid), StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };` this is the correct return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfileImage(string url)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

            try
            {
                //Initalize configuration settings
                var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:name"];
                var accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:key"];
                var profilepicturecontainername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage:account:profilepicscontainername"];

                //Instance objects needed to store the files
                var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(profilepicturecontainername);

                //Gets blob reference
                var cloudBlob = await blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(new Uri(url));

                //Check if it exists
                var cloudBlobExists = await cloudBlob.ExistsAsync();

                //Opens memory stream
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    cloudBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);

                    return File(ms, "application/octet-stream");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what did you change? only the return type?

Comment: and why octect stream?

Comment: I change the return type '<IActionResult>' and I change the return by 'File' because you want return a file image

Comment: which namespace is IActionResult from? please note I am using .net framework, not .net Core., I also get an error on File  line

Comment: Ok If you use .net Framework, use IHttpActionResult in System.Web.Http namespace, I will change my response